# Vuejs: how to implement reactively disable datepicker

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

im newbie here. I want control the datepicker to be disabled automatically based on the existing api. I using the [vuejs-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker-fixed-disabled-dates#disabled-dates) library. I've seen the documentation and managed to implement it statically, but having problems when implementing it reactively.

This is my previous view:

```
<datepicker 
    :disabled-dates="state.disabledDates">
</datepicker>
```

And, my previous static value of datepicker, especially for the day:

```
data() {
    var year = (new Date()).getFullYear()
    var month = (new Date()).getMonth()
    var dDate = (new Date()).getDate()
    
    var state = {
        disabledDates: {
            to: new Date(year, month, dDate), // Disable all dates up to specific date
            // from: new Date(2020, 0, 26), // Disable all dates after specific date
            days: [0,1], // Disable Saturday's and Sunday's
        }
    }
    return {
        
        state: state,

        day: '',        
    }
},
```

For now, here my view:

```
<datepicker 
    :disabled-dates="disabledDates">
</datepicker>
```

Console output:

[image]

My script:

```
<script>
data() {
    return {
        day: '',

        year : (new Date()).getFullYear(),
        month : (new Date()).getMonth(),
        dDate : (new Date()).getDate(),
        
    }
},
computed:{
    // reactive
    disabledDates: {
        to: new Date(year, month, dDate), // Disable all dates up to specific date, 2020,8,8
        days: [day], // Disable day, 0,1
    }  
},
watch: {
    'day': function(day){
        console.log('day: '+day)
        return this.day
    },
},
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: So... what is it doing instead? Could you add a few more details? What's going wrong?

Comment: I want the value of the day of "days: [day]" to change dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your only problem is that your syntax for computed properties is wrong. They should be *functions*, since they need to be run. Their dependencies are automatically determined by Vue, and when those change, the function is re-run. So, try this:

```js
data: function() {
  return {
    day: '',
    year: (new Date()).getFullYear(),
    month: (new Date()).getMonth(),
    dDate: (new Date()).getDate()
  };
},
computed: {
  // Here. This should be a function.
  disabledDates: function() {
    return {
      // Make sure to use 'this.' when in a component
      to: new Date(this.year, this.month, this.dDate),
      days: [ this.day ]
    };
  }
},
watch: {
  day: function(day) {
    console.log(`Day: ${day}`);
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to correct, the disableDate function that I want to disable is days: [this.day] not from: this.day

Comment: @Fenz My mistake. I've updated that. A single-element array, correct?

Comment: thanks in advance, I've changed it as you suggested, but Sunday and Monday are still enabled as shown [img-link](https://ibb.co/ws7bjsp)

Comment: but after I replace it with a static value of 0,1 it can be disabled

Comment: What are you setting `day` to? The *string* `"0,1"`?

Comment: no, the data type I gave is an integer, example test : 0

Comment: @Fenz It seems that `vuejs-datepicker` is expecting an array of integers. So, how are you changing `this.day`? You set it to a single value, (like `0`) and expect... what? That single day to be disabled? Everything up to that day? In this current example, setting `this.day` to `0` should disable Sundays, and `1` should disable Mondays. To do anything else, you'd need to change the code to have the `days: ` key be an Array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. that's right, in my watch it changes into the form first "day = this.day.split ()" then in disableDates on computed i changes "days: this.day"